# Node.js, Express, MongoDB stack: want response to stay on same page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response

I have written a one-page app using Node and Express. This page has several sections, each with a form on it. I POST the data from each form to Mongo, but would like to find a response that stays on the same page, and without refreshing the page. Here is my router code:

```
/* POST data to visitorSessionsTest collection */

router.post('/datasubmit', function(req, res) {

    // Set internal DB variables
    var db = req.db;

    // Get form values.
    var questionId = req.body.questionId;
    var visitorData = req.body.visitorData;

    // Set collection
    var collection = db.get('visitorSessionsTest');

    // Submit to the DB
    collection.insert({
        "questionId" : questionId,
        "visitorData" : visitorData
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            // If it failed, return error
            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        } 
        else {
            // what can go here?

        );
        }
    });
});
```

Even better would be to have the response write innerHTML to a div in the appropriate section on that page reflecting that the data was collected.

**UPDATE** Client-side code begins in Jade, but the relevant part amounts to a series of forms with inputs, like this:

```
<form id="data-submit" name="datasubmit" method="post" action="/datasubmit">
<button name="visitorData" value="16" type="submit" onclick="showMessage(0)">16</button>
....
```

Comment: You may want to use ajax. Call the post/get through ajax. Once the response received, utilize i.e jquery to update the div with the response

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to read up on RESTful API's a bit; there's a lot of common approaches to this kind of thing that aren't node-specific.

That said, what I'd do in your place is to send a 201 ("Created") response, along with a copy of the object created including whatever is needed to navigate to it later (e.g. the ID if your GET routes are based on the object ID).

```
res.status(201).send({id:doc._id, whatever:else, you:want});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it redirects is because of  `type="submit"` on the button. If you remove that and submit the form just through ajax express won't route to the next page